# Регулярные выражения: Объединение условий

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужна ваша помощь. Я новичок в работе с регулярными выражениями. У меня есть три отдельных регулярных выражения.

1. Только символы: `/^[!@#$%^&*]+$/`
2. Только числа: `/^\d+$/`
3. Только буквы: `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`

Как должно выглядеть регулярное выражение, чтобы все эти условия сбывались , не зависимо от порядка? Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 0):

Их можно объединить при помощи логического ИЛИ `|`:

```js
/^([!@#$%^&*]+|\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$/
```

[Пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ucIyGD/1) -- выполняется какое-либо одно из условий -- только символы, только цифры или только буквы.

---

Если нужно проверить, чтобы были как минимум одна буква, одна цифра и один символ, следует применить позитивный просмотр вперёд (*positive lookahead*) `(?=)`, тогда минимальная возможная длина будет 3 символа:

```js
/^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*]).{3,}$/
```

---

В простейшем случае объединение может подразумевать, что должен быть один любой символ:

```js
/^[\dA-Za-z!@#$%^&*]+$/
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я имел в виду, чтобы три условия сбывались. Если введена прописная или строчная буква вместе с символом и цифрой - условие сбывается.

Comment: То есть чтобы были обязательно как минимум одна буква, один символ и одна цифра (т.е. минимальная длина 3)?

Comment: Да, обязательно, не зависимо от порядка. Но длину я определяю с помощью валидации в input

Comment: /^[!@#$%^&*\da-zA-Z]+$/

Comment: @MedvedevDev, это совершенно другая упрощённая проверка

Comment: Спасибо вам большое) `/^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*]).{3,}$/` - работает

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :) Если ответ был полезен, можете отметить его зеленой галочкой и/или проголосовать за него